# How to transpose a column and get the count and percentage of same values in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have dataframe like below.

```
  Q1   Q2
   1    2    
   2    3 
   3    4
   4    1
   1    4
   2    3
```

what i want to do is, i want to transpose each column into rows and get the count of same values and percentage.

my expected output should be

```
    1    2  33%
Q1  2    2  33%
    3    1  16% 
    4    1  16%

    1    1  16%
Q2  2    1  16% 
    3    2  33%
    4    2. 33%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) and then convert `Series` to one colum DataFrame by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html). For percentages divide by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) summed values per first `a` level:

```
df1 = (df.melt(var_name='a', value_name='b')
         .groupby('a')['b']
         .value_counts(sort=False)
         .to_frame(name='count'))
df1['perc'] = df1['count'].div(df1['count'].sum(level=0), 0).mul(100)
print (df1)
      count       perc
a  b                  
Q1 1      2  33.333333
   2      2  33.333333
   3      1  16.666667
   4      1  16.666667
Q2 1      1  16.666667
   2      1  16.666667
   3      2  33.333333
   4      2  33.333333
```

If need percentages:

```
df1['perc'] = df1['perc'].astype(int).astype(str).add('%')
print (df1)
      count perc
a  b            
Q1 1      2  33%
   2      2  33%
   3      1  16%
   4      1  16%
Q2 1      1  16%
   2      1  16%
   3      2  33%
   4      2  33%
```

Comment: holy!! are you a wizard or what? thank you a lot!!!
one last thing not necessary if you can, i am getting Q10 after Q1 not Q2, any way to sort the order like Q1, Q2, Q3 ........ Q10.

Comment: @GetSome_ - You can add `df1 = df1.reindex(df.columns, level=0)`